# How to build and install source package (tarball) in Julia

Tags: package, julia

I seem not able to find concise information online on how to create and install a private source distribution of a Julia module I created.

For comparison, in R, if I have a local project 'mypackage' I can run `devtools::build()` to generate `mypacakge_version.tar.gz` and I can install it using `install.packages("path to mypacakge_version.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`.

In python, I can build a source package by executing `python3 -m build` from the terminal (in the module folder), generating `mypacakge-version.tar.gz`, and I can install it using `pip install "path to mypacakge-version.tar.gz"`.

What are the equivalent procedures in Julia? To be clear, the purpose here is to distribute the software to other people. I don't want to make the package public or create a GitHub repo for it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local pkg using [PkgTemplate](https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl) (this will still create a git repository, but local), work on your package, zip it, redistribuite it and ask your public to locally unzip it and add it with `] add path/to/the/pkg/you/unzipped`, but I am not aware of a more direct way, because Julia pkg system is very rooted in git repositories that aren't so commonly shared in this way...